# How do I access the value of a variable in one function without calling the entire function in Python

Tags: python, function

The issue I'm having is that in one of my functions ( function `range_and_number()` ), I'm asking the user for input, and I'm saving this input in a variable called `max number`. Next I checked to make sure that this value only has numbers in it, and if it does I break the loop.

```py
def range_and_number():
    while True:
        max_number = input("Max Number Possible (No Decimals): ") 
        if max_number.isnumeric() == True:
            print("Your Good")
            max_number = int(max_number)
            break
        else:
            print("Please Re-Type Your Maximum Number: ")

    return max_number

def get_length():
    lives = len(range_and_number)
    
    return lives

def main():
    s = get_length()
    print(f"================= {s} =================")
```

**Issue:** I want to access **the value of** `max number` in another function ( function `get_length()` ) because in this function, I want to measure the length of characters in the variable 'max number'.

The error I'm getting is:

```
lives = len(range_and_number)                                
TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()
```

I understand why I'm getting the error, but how do I get around it. How do I access the value stored in `max_number` without calling the function itself.

P.S. If you have the time, please post as many possible solutions please. Thanks in advance

(What I tried)

- I tried using a Global Variable and created it at the top of my function
- I named the Global Variable TE
- Then, I did `TE = max_number`
- After, I tried accessing TE in the second function, but it didn't work

Comment: You need to call the function: `range_and_number()`. but it returns a number, which doesn't have a length, so what do you expect `len()` to do with that?

Comment: when you tried global variables did you make sure to use the "global" keyword in range_and_number()?

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question does not make sense as asked, because it is based on a misunderstanding. Variables are not "in" the function in the sense that you are thinking; they **only** have a value **because** the function is called; and that value is **specific to each time** that the function is called.

Comment: Think about it this way: it sounds like you want, for some reason, not to have to call `range_and_number`. But if `range_and_number` does not get called, then **where is the information supposed to come from**? `max_number` depends on the user's input, right? So, at the very least, `input` would have to be called, in order to get the user to input something. And this can only happen if `range_and_number` is called, because that's **where the code is** to call `input`.

Comment: It's also not clear to me what the title is supposed to mean, about "calling the entire function". Why "entire"? That doesn't make any sense. A function either gets called or it doesn't. It's a set of steps to follow. If you only want some of those steps to happen, then **make a different function** that only does those steps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `()` after a function name to call it.

You can't get the length of an integer, so you need to convert it to a string in order to call `len()`.

```
def get_length():
    lives = len(str(range_and_number()))
    
    return lives
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function and convert it to string:

```
s = range_and_number().__str__().__len__()
```

or print the `len(max_number)` before converting it to `int`

or you could use logarithm to calculate the length after converting it to `int`dough it would be unnecessary and inefficient when you already have the length of string.

Fancy way of doing it:

```
Y = lambda f: (lambda x: x(x))(lambda y: f(lambda *args: y(y)(*args)))
range_and_number = lambda f: lambda s: (s.__len__() if (s:=input(s)) and s.isnumeric() else f("Please Re-Type Your Maximum Number: \n"))
print("================= %d ================="%Y(range_and_number)('Max Number Possible (No Decimals): \n'))
```

Comment: Hi. Could you please explain why you are recommending `x.__str__().__len__()` rather than `len(str(x))`?

Comment: There is no apparent difference between `len()` and `__len__()` the `len` function will just call the `__len__`(same with string,repr,unicode) method on your string object at the end. I just used to writing it that way so i don't have to navigate to inside of the parentheses, it's also less operations at the end of the day with string function since it does some [extra checking](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str).

Answer (score 0):

> **Issue:** I want to access the value of max number in another function ( function get_length() ) because in this function, I want to measure the length of characters in the variable 'max number'.
>
> - I tried using a Global Variable and created it at the top of my function

Don't use a global variable. Use a variable in function `main`.

```py
def range_and_number():
    while True:
        max_number_as_string = input("Max Number Possible (No Decimals): ")
        try:
            max_number = int(max_number_as_string)
            print("You're good.")
            return max_number
        except ValueError:
            print("Please Re-Type Your Maximum Number.")

def get_length(n):
    return len(str(n))

def main():
    max_number = range_and_number()
    lives = get_length(max_number)
    print('Lives:      {}'.format(lives))
    print('Max number: {}'.format(max_number))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Max Number Possible (No Decimals): hello
Please Re-Type Your Maximum Number.
Max Number Possible (No Decimals): 127.5
Please Re-Type Your Maximum Number.
Max Number Possible (No Decimals): 127
You're good.
Lives:      3
Max number: 127
```

Answer (score -1):

The function get_length should call the function range_and_number. Your code should be something like this.

```py
def range_and_number():
    while True:
        max_number = input("Max Number Possible (No Decimals): ") 
        if max_number.isnumeric() == True:
            print("Your Good")
            max_number = int(max_number)
            break
        else:
            print("Please Re-Type Your Maximum Number: ")

    return max_number

def get_length():
    lives = len(str(range_and_number()))
    
    return lives

def main():
    s = get_length()
    print(f"================= {s} =================")
```